# D3js: How to update children inside <g> when using brush selection?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js, updates

I'm trying to modify a dataviz layout in order to group a `rect` and a `a` below a `g` element. Display works, but when I updated my brush selection everything go to hell as event that should be remove from the canvas are not...

#### Layout

```
<g class="zoomed-event" transform="translate(276,0)">
    <rect width="110" height="42">
    </rect>
    <a xlink:href="…" target="_blank" transform="translate(0, 0)">
        <text transform="translate(2,12)" class="event-label" text-anchor="start">…</text>
    </a>
</g>
```

#### Preview

[image: update and removal fail]

#### Zoom events code

The core of the `drawZoomedEvents` minor helper methods:

```
  const zoomedEvents = zoomArea
    .selectAll('.zoomed-event')
    .data(visibleEvents, (d) => d)
    .attr('transform', (d) => `translate(${xEvent(d)},${y(d)})`)
    .enter()
    .append('g')
    .attr('class', 'zoomed-event')
    .attr('transform', (d) => `translate(${xEvent(d)},${y(d)})`)

  // eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
  const rects = zoomedEvents
    .insert('rect')
    .attr('width', (d) => width(d))
    .attr('height', (d) => yStartPoint(1))
    .attr('style', (d) => colorize(d.lane))

  // eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
  const links = zoomedEvents
    .insert('a')
    .attr('xlink:href', (d) => d.url)
    .attr('target', '_blank')
    .attr('transform', (d) => `translate(${xLink(d)}, 0)`)
    .append('text')
    .text((d) => title(d))
    .attr('transform', 'translate(2,12)')
    .attr('class', 'event-label')
    .attr('text-anchor', 'start')

  zoomedEvents.exit().remove()

  return zoomedEvents
}
```

#### Brush

Not sure that's needed but, I call `drawZoomedEvents` like this:

```
const drawBrush = (data, { x, xStartPoint, yStartPoint }, zoomArea) => {
  const selection = d3.event && d3.event.selection
  if (!selection) return
  let [selectionStart, selectionEnd] = selection.map(x.invert)
  let visibleEvents = data.filter(
    (event) => event.end > selectionStart && event.start < selectionEnd
  )

  xStartPoint.domain([selectionStart, selectionEnd])

  drawZoomedEvents(zoomArea, visibleEvents, {
    xStartPoint,
    yStartPoint,
    selectionStart,
  })
}
```

#### Code

Repo is open-source: [coronavirus-policies-timeline](https://github.com/edouard-lopez/coronavirus-policies-timeline/commit/fa61afd631d0848564458f47671acd391ad28513), see [ZoomedEvents.js](https://github.com/edouard-lopez/coronavirus-policies-timeline/blob/fa61afd631d0848564458f47671acd391ad28513/src/Timeline/ZoomedEvents.js) file.